# Can not archive build in xcode with cocoa pods

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, afnetworking, cocoapods, ocmock

I'm using xCode 6.3.2 and pods of 0.37.2. I have one main target and one test target, pod file looks like :

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'

target :'UnitTest' do
 pod 'OCMock',      '~> 3.1'   # OCMock
end
```

Also i am using config files, that include both "Pods.debug.xcconfig" and "Pods Tests.debug.xcconfig"

while trying to make an archive i get an error:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-UnitTest-AFNetworking
```

If I use run with simulator - it works well.
What can be the reason of such strange issue?

Answer (score 0):

One I have this problem I fixed this way :

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'

target :UnitTest, :exclusive => true do
 pod 'OCMock',      '~> 3.1'   # OCMock
end
```

**exclusive => true do** this is the trick. Hope it will work for you too.

Comment: @alex is everything OK now?